# Show a PDE satisfies a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $u(x,t)$ satisfies the partial differential equation $${du\over dt} = \frac 12 {d^2u\over dx^2}$$ for all $t>0$ and $x\in R$, and also that has functional form $$u(x,t) = t^\alpha\omega(\theta)$$ where $$\theta=\frac x{\sqrt{t}}$$ How do I show that $\omega(\theta)$ must satisfy the following ordinary differential equation $$\omega'' + (\theta\omega)' = (1+2\alpha)\omega,$$ for all $\theta\in R$

I have tried to rearrange the functional form in terms of $\omega$, and diffentiate w.r.t. $t$, but not arriving at intended destination

Comment: The second term of the answer is $\theta^\prime \omega + \theta + \omega^\prime$. However, $\theta^\prime$ seems undefined because $\theta$ is a function of two variables, $x$ and $t$. So I do not know what the ODE really represents. Unless $x(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(t^\alpha w(\theta))\\
        &=\alpha t^{\alpha-1}w(\theta)+t^\alpha\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}w'(\theta)\\
        &=\alpha t^{\alpha-1}w(\theta)+t^\alpha\left(-\frac{1}{2t}\theta\right)w'(\theta)\\
        &=t^{\alpha-1}(\alpha\, w(\theta)-\theta/2\;w'(\theta))\\[10pt]
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=t^\alpha\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}w'(\theta)\\
        &=t^{\alpha-1/2}w'(\theta)\\[10pt]
    \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}&=t^{\alpha-1}w''(\theta)
\end{align}
$$

Put it all together, notice that for $t\not=0$ we can simplify by $t^{\alpha-1}/2$ and get
$$
    2\alpha\,w(\theta)=w''(\theta)+\theta\,w'(\theta).
$$
Using the fact that $(\theta\,w)'=w+\theta\,w'$, we finally get
$$
    w''+(\theta\,w)'=(1+2\alpha)w.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much @zuggg.  Just one question, when simplifying ${d\theta\over dt}$, did you use ${d\theta\over dx}$${dx\over dt}$? To work through this using $\theta = xt^{-1\over 2}$ and $x=\theta t^{1\over 2}$ I get ${d\theta\over dx}=t^{-1\over 2}$ and ${dx\over dt}={1\over 2}\theta t^{-1\over 2}$.  

Where am I going wrong?  I can't seem to get the negative sign for the differentiation ${d\theta\over dt}$

Comment: @user85734 I used
$$
    \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(xt^{-1/2})=(-1/2)xt^{-3/2}=(-1/2)\theta/t
$$

Comment: very slick!  Thank you!

Comment: @user85734 Also, the reason you found an incorrect result with your method is because you cannot simply use the chain rule here, it is slightly more complicated:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\right)_{\!\theta}=\left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\right)_{\!t}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)_{\!\theta}+\left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\right)_{\!x}\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}\right)_{\!\theta}
$$

Comment: thus
$$
0=\left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\right)_{\!t}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)_{\!\theta}+\left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}\right)_{\!x}
$$
if you really want to see each variable as a function of the two others.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: all the ordinary derivatives you write are, in reality, partial derivatives. You have

$$2\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}, $$

with

$$u(x,t)=t^{\alpha}\omega(\theta(x,t)) $$

and $\theta(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}.$ Then your PDE is equivalent to

$$2\alpha t^{\alpha-1}\omega(\theta(x,t))+2t^{\alpha}\frac{\partial \omega(\theta(x,t))}{\partial t}=t^{\alpha}\frac{\partial^2 \omega(\theta(x,t))}{\partial x^2}. $$

All you need now is to apply the chain rule on the partial derivatives applied to the composite function $\omega(\theta(x,t))$. Can you do this?

Comment: Thank you so much @Avitus.  So essentially replacing the $${dw\over dt}={dw\over d\theta}{d\theta\over dt}=w' .(-{1\over 2}xt^{-{3\over 2}})$$ and the $${d^2w\over dx^2}={d^2w\over d\theta^2}{d^2\theta\over dx^2}=w''.(zero?)$$  Where am I going wrong @Avitus?

Comment: Sorry for delay in answering! The problem is with the second derivative: in fact $\frac{\partial^2 \omega}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x})=...$, which is a sum of more than one contribution. This becomes evident if you write the product in the brackets as $g(\theta(x,t))\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$: applying the chain rule to the first term you get the $\omega''$ contribution to your ODE.